# Get JSON from another sheet in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: json, url, google-sheets, uri, google-sheets-api

I already know that I can get the default sheet with this format url
`https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/mysheetid/od6/public/basic?alt=json`

and I saw when I toggle to another sheet, basically google spreadsheet just add `gid=1234` when edit.

So I did 
`https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/mysheetid/od6/public/basic?alt=json&gid=1234` But I still get the first sheet.

What is the right way to do this?

Scenario:

The specific spreadsheet has made available through link. There are two sheets within a spreadsheet doc.

Comment: Just adding additional information about the answer of Ed Nelson, the parameter in where you place the od6 means that a `grid_id`. This is the parameter that you set if you want to get the specific sheets in your spreadsheet. Note that you cannot place a `grid_id` here or number greater than the number of sheets that you have. Because if you place an invalid number here, you will get an error **"Invalid query parameter value for grid_id."**

Comment: @KENdi thanks for a valuable addition! *smile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace od6 with 1 for the first sheet, 2 for the second sheet and so on. Like:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/mysheetid/2/public/basic?alt=json
```